# why i have different cookie value on different page?

Tags: php, cookies

I use several cookie, one to them for city detect and search.
why it has different value on different pages? For example right value on the index page and the wrong on page /place.php?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that the two cookies are valid for different paths.

https://www.php.net/setcookie

> **`path`:** The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.

When you set your cookies, use a path value of `/` to make them valid across the entire domain.

Comment: (string)$location = $_GET['city_id'];
setcookie("location", $location, time()+60*60*24*30, '/');

Comment: i wrote /, but it doesn't help.

Comment: @Viktor You should look in your browser's developer console. See what cookies are present. You might consider clearing them after the `/` change, too.